# mysql_num_rows for an mysql object?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

How do I find mysql_num_rows for an object.

This gives an error:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());   
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);

echo mysql_num_rows( $row );
```

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, object
>   given

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`mysql_num_rows`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) expects a **result set** [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) (the set of results returned by `mysql_query`, ie. what is ending up in your `$query` variable), not on a single row.

This would work:

```
$result_set = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_set);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result_set);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should pass the ***result*** of `mysql_query` to `mysql_num_rows` like this:

```
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
```

**From Docs:**

> The result resource that is being
>   evaluated. This result comes from a
>   call to **mysql_query()**.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

```
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
```

i.e. you need to pass the return value from `mysql_query` to `mysql_num_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. According to *manual page*, which good programmers always refer to, one object contains **one** row.
While mysql_num_rows() works with result set resource.

Also I have to say that according to my experience there is very little use if such a function. I can barely find a case where you would need it.

Comment: Condescension is unnecessary and counterproductive.